# Customising Views Calendar output

Tags: 7, views, datetime

**How can I stop the default output of a Views rendered mini-calendar block?**

I am using Views 7.3.7 to output a calendar of nodes according to a date field.

I don't want the links to the node that I get by default. So rather than have links to my nodes, I can just have an NID associated to each entry in a cell?
I need the NIDs so I can do some AJAX work.

Comment: If you are using the views plugin from the [calendar](https://drupal.org/project/calendar) module, which template did you use?

Comment: @Triskelion: The template is calendar-mini-calendar--block-1.tpl.php